# How to save string entered in UITextField to NSUserDefaults Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, alert, nsuserdefaults

I am creating an app in which i want the user to create their password the first time they open the app. I have an alert pop up that has a textfield and a button I want to save whatever text they enter into the textfield for use later. Here is the code for the alert I have so far.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated);    //You should call super.

    let firstLaunch = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("FirstLaunch")
    if firstLaunch  {
        println("Not first launch.")
    }
    else {
        println("First launch, setting NSUserDefault.")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "FirstLaunch")
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Create Your Password", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save Password", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
            textfield in
            textfield.placeholder = "Password"
            textfield.secureTextEntry = true
        })
}
```

I have no clue where to start for this, and any help would be aprecciated.

Comment: You need to process the text in the handler for your "Save Password" action. Don't pass `nil` for the handler. Provide an actual handler.

Comment: Do not save a password in `NSUserDefault`, it is not secure. You need to save it in the keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Textfield that you are using is limited within the scope of closure. Say I enter password as 12345. Which you can check by checking text property of textfield within closure. But you can't access those properties outside the closure.

Coming back to question. Please change your code like below

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save Password", style:   UIAlertActionStyle.Default)){ (action) in

//set password.
UserDefaults.standard.setValue("12345", forKey: "Password")
}


//Note that password i.e. 12345 is stored as of type Any?. After getting it back from defaults you will have to cast in back to string.
```

I hope it helps.